Is the "dexos" trademark an acronym? What do the letters mean then?
dexos is a General Motors trademark for oil specification. I am interesting is it an abbreviation or maybe this word means something?
For example:

ACEA - l’Association des Constructeurs Européens d’Automobiles.
ILSAC - International Lubricant Specification Advisory Committee.
API - American Petrol Institute.
dexos - ???


The 'dex' prefix is also used by GM for other products, such as Dexron, Dextrol and Dexcool. IDK where the 'dex' part comes from. Perhaps it is just nice-sounding branding.

@WeatherVane Good point. I have checked GM trademarks on justia.com and have found such: DEXRON, DEX-COOL, DEXOS, DEX-CVT. Dextrol is another story - dry cough syrup.

@WeatherVane Can the "DEX-" be related to Detroit? Or DELCO (Dayton Engineering Laboratories Company)?

I did a TM search as well and found the original attorney who filed the TM back in 2008. Thought she might know, but GM bounced the email back to me stating, "Recipient address rejected: Access denied." I guess this means they have a white list of who can actually send them emails, lol. Oh well, back to the drawing board :o)

https://www.gmdexos.com/

I was able to find someone in the know, but they asked to not be mentioned by name as they no longer work for GM in any capacity. This is what they stated ...
The "DEX" alludes to the the "DEX" family of products as you had stated in your comment. These are the names such as "Dex-Cool" (coolant) or "Dexron" (automatic transmission fluid).
EDIT: Rumor has it, the "Dex" is derived from a company named Dexter Laundry who makes commercial laundry equipment. They've been in business since the late 1800's. GM purchased them in 1952 as they were trying to expand the industries beyond automobiles. They owned the company up until the early 80's when they divested their holdings to get back to their automotive roots. Dexter Laundry is now 100% employee owned.
The "OS" is an acronym for "oil specification".

Thanks for help. "OS" as an Oil Specification looks reasonable, I also had such assumption. I wasn't able to google out any information about connection between General Motors and Dexter Laundry. Anyway, such origin of "DEX" is doubtful in my opinion. It can't be taken seriously without some prove or source.

I think an origin of DEX should be traced from DEXRON, which was released in 1967. Can the name Dexron be related to the name Chevron? From Wikipedia "The 'Chevron' name came into use for some of its retail products in the 1930s."
